# Citation throughout my book rather than at the end as a bibliography

Tags: creative-writing, technical-writing, formatting, academic-writing, citations

My book is a health/ wellness/ diet book/ metabolic issues etc. Throughout my book which I am 3/4 of the way through I have added in the website links after a piece of evidence. I have used 95% of my evidence from NCBI, which is ((The National Center for Biotechnology Information is part of the United States National Library of Medicine)), so science backed evidence. How I have placed it in the book is as an example:

Obesity has evolved through the last 30 years on a huge scale due to the rise in blah blah blah blah. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/labs/pmc/articles/PMC4859313/. Then continues writing blah blah blah...

Can someone tell me if this is ok to do this. I have also got a lot of statements as bullet points where I need to have the links in to confirm the facts such as:

- Diabetes is currently 75% of the US population. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/labs/pmc/articles/PMC4859313/

If anyone can tell me that this is ok, that would be much appreciated

Thank you in advance

Comment: Tangentially, I don't see that 75% claim anywhere in the linked article, and it sounds way too high.

Comment: "I have used 95% of my evidence from NCBI" Just in case you're unaware, the articles in PubMed Central are submitted by publishers from all over the world. So they are not "from NCBI" in that sense. It's not a hallmark of quality. So make sure its source is actually from a reputable journal and well-regarded authors.

Answer (score 1):

If you link to journal papers, it is usually best to use the paper's [doi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier). It's a persistent id/link that will redirect to where the official electronic version is located, and most publishers will update it if the location changes.
If the official version is not freely accessible, and there is a url where it is (e.g. on the authors webpage), you could use both links.

I would avoid putting the links in the text, but use numeric references instead. That way readers don't have to ignore as much clutter when reading the text when they're not interested in every article referenced. It also means you can put extra information in the reference such as the title, authors, year, journal and perhaps a relevant quote.
From the popular science books I've read, I'd say the common practice is to put the references and notes in the back of the book - per chapter for easy lookup. However, I think that is usually something the publisher decides on. (So if you don't self-publish, ask them.)
Personally, I would prefer notes as actual footnotes, so I'm not constantly flipping back and forth between the current page and the notes in the back of the book. On the other hand I'm rarely interested in purely bibliographic references, so I'm happy for those to be tucked away at the back of the book.

NB If you distribute your book as e-publication, you could probably fairly easily make different versions with most variations people might wish for.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is apparently a popular rather than an academic work, you are free to adopt whatever standard that you like. Providing evidence to back up assertions is good practice, however you do it. If this is an ebook or online work, providing hyperlinks is particularly useful to a reader.

You should be aware that even major sites can change organization or go offline, sometimes without warning. It might be well to add footnotes or end notes in which you quote relevant parts of the text at those links (with proper attribution), in case the links stop working. You might also want to consider not relying so heavily on a single source, however high-quality it may be.